# Workflow for embedding corporate-looking 3D models into presentation slides

Tags: 3d, presentation-design

I have recently discovered Pitch and on their website https://pitch.com they are using a lot of 3D assets blended into the 2D slide designs. I've seen this style of corporate design at several other brands before, but as I am still quite new to 3D design, I do not really know what to even search for to be able to reproduce this style. Some questions:

- The 3D models seem quite simple (rounded corners and comparably low-poly and/or simple geometry), whereas many 3D model assets I find elsewhere on the internet are too detailed. What are some websites or 3D model databases where I can find models that are shaped similarly to the ones shown below?
- The shading and the shadows are also quite particular and I quite like this style. How can this shading be achieved with 3D modeling software?
- From a workflow perspective, I feel like using a very versatile software like Blender seems a bit overkill and inflexible. When embedding a rendered 3D model into a presentation, I would need to model it in Blender first (i.e. also adjust all the shading, lighting, camera position and colors manually), then export a PNG and finally add this PNG to the presentation slides. Instead of being this static and tedious, I'd like the process of embedding 3D imagery into a presentation to be very dynamic, fast and responsive. Is there any software which makes this easier, i.e. essentially a combination of PowerPoint/Google Presentations and a very simplified version of Blender?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe a tool like [Vectary](https://vectary.com) might be pretty much what you are looking for. It offers a direct `.png` download option as mentioned on their [docs](https://help.vectary.com/file-exporting#block-1ccc3c9309d8471aa22e10529fea94c3). On their page about the "[3D configurator](https://www.vectary.com/3d-configurator/)" (as I understand it that is their name for web-embedding the 3D scenes) they even mention direct export to Pitch. It seems likely that Pitch themselves use this tool.

They also mention a [Figma plugin](https://www.vectary.com/figma/) to use Vectary inside Figma.

I have never used the tool so I cannot vouch for it, but I have used enough 3D software to guess that – from what I gather from your explanation – this might be what you are looking for.

Comment: That tool looks really good, definitely does make 3D modeling so much easier! Thanks for the hint, I'll check it out more deeply.